# Is it possible to get the log point on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm wondering if it's possible to log the line/column number when i log an error. The GAE logging lib seems to store only the error message but I think it would be quite valuable to get the exact location of the error/log point like most logging libraries do.

Comment: Your question says "stack trace" but then you ask about file:line of the "log point"; did you look at [`log.Llongfile` or `log.Lshortfile`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Llongfile)? (Or search the docs for "stack trace"?)

Comment: i think GAE log package doesn't provide a log point. You seem to point to the std lib log package. See https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/log

Comment: Wow, that's dumb. I'll have to remember to not bother with GAE if they don't even have basics from the standard library on it.

Answer (score 1):

What you request is definitely possible, you just need to be very explicit about it!  I recommend Andrew Gerrand's excellent article at http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go for general information on the issue, including notes specific to App Engine.

That article does not specifically address stack traces, but of course you could do those yourself, via http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack .

Let's be honest and admit that Go -- being by design more of a system-programming language than of an application-focused one -- doesn't do **quite** as much implicit, automatic hand-holding for you, as more app-oriented languages such as the other App Engine ones -- Java, Python, PHP... [*] but, Go **does** give you all the tools you need to do just as little, or as much, "supporting infrastructure", as you desire to have in support of your own apps!-)

[*] hey, you don't even get automatically by-default propagating **exceptions**, as you do for other languages -- nay, you're responsible for catching and dealing with errors yourself, oh the horror...!-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [runtime](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) package to trace the caller(I assume that's basically what you want). There is no GAE specific issue and it has nothing to do with the error handling.

```
   // The depth specifies how many stack frames above 
   // lives the source line to be identified in the log message.
    func traceCaller(depth int)(string, int){
    _, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(2 + depth)
        if !ok {
            file = "???"
            line = 1
        } else {
            slash := strings.LastIndex(file, "/")
            if slash >= 0 {
                file = file[slash+1:]
            }
        }
        return file, line
}
```